# Does Chrome treat the Content Security Policy HOST as case sensitive?

Tags: google-chrome, security

While building a site in WordPress, Customizer wouldn't load the frame to display the page. Here is the error in Chrome.

> Refused to display 'https://example.com/?customize_changeset_uuid=....' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://Example.com".

Notice the HOST is lowercase in the URL while it's mixed case in the *frame-ancestors* directive. If I change the **WordPress Address (URL)** to lowercase in the WordPress settings, Chrome loads the page. This implies that Chrome treats the HOST as case sensitive. Firefox loads the frame in both cases.

From my brief read through 4.2 Source List Syntax of Content Security Policy Level 2, section [4.2.2. Matching Source Expressions](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#host_source), item 4.7 states the HOST is case insensitive.

> 7. If the first character of the source expression’s host-part is not an U+002A ASTERISK character (*) and url-host is not a case insensitive match for the source expression’s host-part, then return does not match.

Is this a bug with Chrome? Am I misunderstanding CSP2 case sensitivity w/r hosts?

Here are the versions in case anyone is wondering.

- Google Chrome Version 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit) (on openSUSE Leap 15.0)
- Firefox 61.0.2 (64-bit) (on openSUSE Leap 15.0)
- nginx 1.15.2-111.1 (on openSUSE Leap 42.3)
- WordPress 4.9.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No replies usually means it's a bug and nobody has suggestions. [Issue 882145](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=882145) has been opened.